# Prove $a^{\sqrt{\log_ba}}+b^{\sqrt{\log_cb}}+c^{\sqrt{\log_ac}}\geqslant a+b+c$ for $a, b, c > 1$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

> For $$a,b,c > 1$$ show that
> $$a^{\sqrt{\log_ba}}+b^{\sqrt{\log_cb}}+c^{\sqrt{\log_ac}}\geqslant a+b+c$$

I know how to show this $$a^{{\log_bc}}+b^{{\log_ca}}+c^{{\log_ab}}\geqslant a+b+c$$
$$a^{\log_bc}+b^{\log_ca}=a^{\log_bc}+a^{\log_cb}\geq2\sqrt{a^{\log_bc}a^{\log_cb}}=2\sqrt{a^{\log_bc+\log_cb}}\geq2\sqrt{a^2}=2a$$
Or this one $$(ab)^{\sqrt{\log_ab}}+(bc)^{\sqrt{\log_bc}}+(ca)^{\sqrt{\log_ca}}\geqslant a^2+b^2+c^2$$
$$a^{\sqrt{\log_ab}}=b^{\sqrt{\log_ba}}$$
$$(ab)^{\sqrt{\log_a}}=a^{\sqrt{\log_ab}}b^{\sqrt{\log_ab}}=b^{\sqrt{\log_ba}}b^{\sqrt{\log_ab}}=b^{\sqrt{\log_ab}+\sqrt{\log_ba}}\geq b^2$$
Or even  $$a^{{\log_ba}}+b^{{\log_cb}}+c^{{\log_ac}}\geqslant a+b+c$$
But the first one, I don't know how to start. Please give me a starting point.

Comment: Mathlearning, could you write in your post how you show those inequalities ?

Comment: Begin by transforming $\log_ab=\frac{\ln b}{\ln a}$, etc.

Comment: I think I need more than $$log_ab=lnb/lna$$

Comment: But how did you prove those inequalities that you've written down? It's good to know that you could solve them but knowing how you started those inequalities could give us some clue.

Answer (score 10):

It suffices to prove that
$$a^{\sqrt{\log_b a}}
\ge \frac{3a - b}{2}. \tag{1}$$
Summing cyclically on (1), the desired result follows.

---

*Proof of* (1):

We only need to prove the case that $\frac{3a - b}{2} > 1$.

Taking logarithm, it suffices to prove that, for all $1 < b < 3a - 2$,
$$\sqrt{\log_b a}\, \ln a \ge \ln \frac{3a - b}{2}$$
or
$$\sqrt{\ln a}\, \ln a
\ge \sqrt{\ln b}\,\ln \frac{3a - b}{2}$$
or (squaring both sides)
$$\ln^3 a \ge \ln b \cdot \ln \frac{3a - b}{2}\cdot \ln \frac{3a - b}{2}.$$

By AM-GM twice, we have
\begin{align*}
 \ln b \cdot \ln \frac{3a - b}{2}\cdot \ln \frac{3a - b}{2}
 &\le \left(\frac{\ln b + \ln \frac{3a - b}{2} + \ln \frac{3a - b}{2}}{3}\right)^3\\[6pt]
 &= \frac{1}{27}\ln^3  \left(b \cdot \frac{3a-b}{2 } \cdot \frac{3a-b}{2}\right)\\[6pt]
 &\le \frac{1}{27}\ln^3 \left(\left(\frac{b + \frac{3a - b}{2} + \frac{3a - b}{2}}{3}\right)^3\right)\\[6pt]
 &= \frac{1}{27}\ln^3(a^3) \\
 &= \ln^3 a.
\end{align*}

We are done.

Comment: I cannot do better without using derivative.+1 Are you a teacher?

Comment: @ErikSatie Thanks.

Comment: This is a nice proof.

Answer (score 5):

Define functions $g(t) = \exp(\exp(t))$, $f(t_1, t_2, t_3) = g(t_1) + g(t_2) + g(t_3)$.

Let $\displaystyle \begin{cases}x_1 = \ln\ln a\\ x_2 = \ln\ln b\\ x_3 = \ln\ln c\end{cases}$,
and set $\begin{cases}y_1 = \frac{3x_1 - x_2}{2}\\ y_2 = \frac{3x_2 - x_3}{2}\\ y_3 = \frac{3x_3 - x_1}{2}\end{cases}$, then we can rewrite the inequality as
$$ f\left(y_1, y_2, y_3\right)\geq f(x_1, x_2, x_3). \tag{#}$$

To establish (#), note that

1. $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ [is majorized by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization) $(y_1, y_2, y_3)$, since
   $$
   \begin{bmatrix}
   x_1\\
   x_2\\
   x_3
   \end{bmatrix}
   = 
   \begin{bmatrix}
   \frac32&-\frac12&0\\
   0&\frac32&-\frac12\\
   -\frac12&0&\frac32
   \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
   \begin{bmatrix}
   y_1\\
   y_2\\
   y_3
   \end{bmatrix}
   =\begin{bmatrix}
   \frac9{13}&\frac3{13}&\frac1{13}\\
   \frac1{13}&\frac9{13}&\frac3{13}\\
   \frac3{13}&\frac1{13}&\frac9{13}
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
   y_1\\
   y_2\\
   y_3
   \end{bmatrix},
   $$
   and the matrix in the last term is [doubly stochastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix).
2. $f$ is [Schur-convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur-convex_function), since $g$ is convex.

---

***Remarks***

1. An alternative way is to show that
   $$g(y_1) = g\left(\frac{3x_1 - x_2}{2}\right) \geq \frac{3g(x_1) - g(x_2)}{2}, \tag{##}$$
   (and also the other two inequalities for $g(y_2), g(y_3)$),
   which can be established from the convexity of $g$.
   Eq. (##) is indeed Eq. (1) in River Li's nice construction.
2. From the convexity of $g$, we can extend (##) to
   $$g\left((1+p)x_1 - p x_2\right) \geq (1+p)g(x_1) - p\cdot g(x_2), \quad \text{for all $p > 0$},$$
   where (##) is the special case of $p = 1/2$.
   This says that, essentially, we have
   $$
   a^{(\log_ba)^p}+b^{(\log_cb)^p}+c^{(\log_ac)^p}\geqslant a+b+c, \quad \text{for all $p > 0$ and $a, b, c > 1$.}
   $$

Comment: Nice answer using majorization.

Comment: Remark 2 is interesting.

Comment: @RiverLi Thx! After comparing it with your construction, I realized that Jensen's inequality could be more convenient than majorization, which led to the extension (Remark 2).

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 2):

Some hint (hard to do better than the RiverLi's answer) :

Using derivative try to show :

for $x>1,y>1$ we have :

$$x^{\sqrt{\frac{\ln x}{\ln y}}}-1-\left(x-1\right)\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{y-1}}\geq 0$$

Then we need to show :

$$\sum_{cyc}1+\left(x-1\right)\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{y-1}}-x\geq 0$$

Try the substitution : $u^2=x-1,v^2=y-1,w^2=z-1$

Hope you enjoy it .

Ps: I shall add details later .

Adding details :

A bit of algebra (using the subsitution i give) we need to show :

$$\ln^3(x^2+1)\geq \ln^2(x^3/y+1)\ln(y^2+1)$$

We can  prove it using :

Let $x>0,y>0,z>0$

Then we have :

$$(\ln((xyz)^{1/3}+1))^3-\ln(x+1)\ln(y+1)\ln(z+1)\ge 0$$

It's straightforward.It's itself show with the log concavity of :

$$\ln(\ln(e^x+1))$$

Answer (score 2):

$\color{green}{\textbf{Useful inequality.}}$

Firstly, let us consider the function
$$f(x,y,z)=x^4z+y^4x+z^4y-xyz(x^2+y^2+z^2),\qquad (x>0,\;y>0,\;z>0),\tag 1$$
which has the gradient
$$\bar\nabla f(x,y.z) =
\begin{pmatrix}
y^4+3x^3z-(3x^2+y^2+z^2)yz\\
z^4+3y^3x-(3y^2+z^2+x^2)zx\\
x^4+3z^3y-(3z^2+x^2+y^2)xy
\end{pmatrix},$$
Easily to check, that
$$(\bar\nabla f((x,y,z))\cdot (x,y,z) = 5f(x,y,z).$$
Therefore, $\,f(x,y,z)=0\,$in the stationary points.

Taking in account that
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x,y,z)= +\infty,\quad
\lim_{y\to \infty} f(x,y,z)= +\infty,\quad
\lim_{z\to \infty} f(x,y,z)= +\infty,$$
this means, that the inequality
$$f(x,y,z)\ge 0,\qquad(x>0,\;y>0,\;z>0)\tag2$$
is satisfied on the edges of the domain and, as the result,
in the all points of the domain.

$\color{green}{\textbf{Main proof.}}$

Let $\;\ln a=x^2,\quad \ln b = y^2,\quad \ln c=z^2, \quad x>0,\;y>0,\;z>0,$ then

$$\large a^{\sqrt{\log_ba}}=e^{\ln a \sqrt{\frac {\ln a}{\ln b}}}
=e^{\frac{x^3}y}.$$

Taking in account $(2),$ one can get:
$$a^{\sqrt{\log_ba}}+b^{\sqrt{\log_cb}}+c^{\sqrt{\log_ac}}-(a+b+c)
=e^{^{x^3}/y}+e^{^{y^3}/z}+e^{^{z^3}/x} -\left(e^{x^2}+e^{y^2}+e^{z^2}\right)$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac1{k!}\left(\dfrac{x^{3k}}{y^k} +\dfrac{y^{3k}}{z^k}+\dfrac{z^{3k}}{x^k}-x^{2k}-y^{2k}-z^{2k}\right) 
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac1{k!x^ky^kz^k}\, f\left(x^k,y^k,z^k\right)
\color{brown}{\mathbf{\ge 0.}}$$

Proved.

Comment: I think your inequality :
$$\sum\dfrac{x^3}{y} - \sum x^2\geq 0$$
it's much simpler with rearrangement.

Comment: @dezdichado Very interesting generalization, thanks!

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov I found it before you but it's not the same as proof .I found it using fasly  Bernoulli's inequality.

Comment: @ErikSatie Easily to see, that I have not use your ideas. Honestly, my original way requires less efforts than plagiarism.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Yes .