# Prove that $ a^{\log_b(a)} + b^{\log_c(b)} + c^{\log_a(c)} \geq a^{\sqrt{\log_b(a)}} + b^{\sqrt{\log_c(b)}} + c^{\sqrt{\log_a(c)}} \geq a + b + c$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, contest-math, rearrangement-inequality

Let $ a, b, c > 1 $. Prove that
$ a^{\log_b(a)} + b^{\log_c(b)} + c^{\log_a(c)} \geq a^{\sqrt{\log_b(a)}} + b^{\sqrt{\log_c(b)}} + c^{\sqrt{\log_a(c)}} \geq a + b + c. $

My approach: I denoted $ \log_b(a) = x ,  \log_c(b) = y , and  \log_a(c) = z$. Then our inequality becomes
$ a^x + b^y + c^z \geq a^{\sqrt{x}} + b^{\sqrt{y}} + c^{\sqrt{z}} \geq b^x + c^y + a^z. $
I tried applying rearrangement inequality, but I couldn't find the ordering of $(x, y, z)$.

Comment: Please add some more work/context/source/motivation etc, to prevent this question from getting closed.

Comment: The right inequality was proved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4653507/prove-a-sqrt-log-bab-sqrt-log-cbc-sqrt-log-ac-geqslant-abc

Comment: I wonder how you apply rearrangement inequality, if there are exponents and not products.

Comment: @RiverLi does any manipulation to the method in the answer give the left inequality?

Comment: @DS There was this generalised form of the rearrangement inequality $(a_{i_1})^{x_1} + (a_{i_2})^{x_2} + \ldots + (a_{i_n})^{x_n} \leq (a_1)^{x_1} + \ldots + (a_n)^{x_n}$

This happens if and only if  $a_1, \ldots, a_n > 1$ and $x_1, \ldots, x_n > 0$ are both strictly the same ordered.

Comment: @DS I think we may use Karamata's inequality. Need some works.

Comment: Not much work is needed but, as $\sum x^4/y^2$ majorizes $\sum x^2$, no?

Comment: @DS How does $∑^4/^2$ majorize $∑^2$?

Comment: I meant to say $\sum x^4/y^2 \ge \sum x^2$ by rearrangement

Comment: @DS how would we apply Karamata for the left inequality?

Comment: River Li deleted a comment before I could fully comprehend it, but I think his approach was valid.

Comment: @RiverLi could you help us applying Karamata?

Answer (score 2):

For the left inequality:

Let $x := \frac12 \ln \ln a, y := \frac12 \ln \ln b, z := \frac12 \ln \ln c$.
The desired left inequality is written as
$$\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{e}^{4x - 2y}}
+ \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{e}^{4y - 2z}} + \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{e}^{4z - 2x}}
\ge \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{e}^{3x - y}} + \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{e}^{3y - z}} + \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{e}^{3z - x}}. \tag{1}$$

Note that $u \mapsto \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{e}^{u}}$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}$ (easy by checking second derivative).

Let $U := 4x - 2y, V := 4y - 2z, W := 4z - 2x, X := 3x - y, Y := 3y - z, Z := 3z - x$.

Since (1) is cyclic, assume that $x = \max(x, y, z)$.

We split into two cases.

**Case 1.** $x \ge y \ge z$

Clearly, we have $U + V + W = X + Y + Z$.

We have
$U - W = 6x - 2y - 4z \ge 0$,
$V - W = 4y - 6z + 2x \ge 0$,
$X - Z = 4x - y - 3z \ge 0$,
$Y - Z = 3y - 4z + x \ge 0$
which results in $W = \min(U, V, W)$ and $Z = \min(X, Y, Z)$.
We have $U + V - (X + Y) = x - z \ge 0$.

Also, we have $U - X = x - y \ge 0$ and $V - Y = y - z \ge 0$
which results in $\max(U, V) \ge \max(X, Y)$.

Thus, $(X, Y, Z)$ is majorized by
$(U, V, W)$. By [Karamata's inequality](https://www.detailedpedia.com/wiki-Karamata%27s_inequality),
(1) is true.

**Case 2.** $x \ge z \ge y$

Clearly, $U + V + W = X + Y + Z$.

We have
$U - W = 6x - 2y - 4z \ge 0$,
$U - V = 4x - 6y + 2z \ge 0$,
$X - Z = 4x - y - 3z \ge 0$,
$X - Y = 3x - 4y + z \ge 0$ which results in
$U = \max(U, V, W)$ and $X = \max(X, Y, Z)$.
We have $U - X = x - y \ge 0$.

Also, we have
$U + V - (X + Y) = x -z \ge 0$,
and $U + W - (X + Z) = z - y \ge 0$ which results in
$\max(U + V, U + W) \ge \max(X + Y, X + Z)$.

Thus, $(X, Y, Z)$ is majorized by
$(U, V, W)$. By Karamata's inequality,
(1) is true.

We are done.

Comment: I understood the second inequality thanks to the link but as in for the first one I have no idea how to approach

Comment: @DS typo. left inequality.

Comment: @math.enthusiast9 typo, for left inequality. I will complete it.

Comment: nice! Also, in a contest, can we directly state (U,V,W) majorizes (X,Y,Z) (your proof is little bit long but obvious)?

Comment: @DS I don't know if there is simple approach for majorization. Another way is to use the fact that $Y$ is majorized by $X$ if there exists a row-stochastic matrix $A$ such that $AX = Y$. We have
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 11/14 & 1/7 & 1/14 \\
 1/14 & 11/14 & 1/7 \\
 1/7 & 1/14 & 11/14
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
 4x - 2y \\
 4y - 2z \\
 4z - 2x
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
 3x - y \\
 3y - z \\
 3z - x
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Thus, $(3x-y, 3y-z, 3z-x)$ is majorized by $(4x-2y, 4y-2z, 4z - 2x)$.

Comment: I am not asking for an alternate way of proving majorization. I'm just asking whether the proof of majorization may be skipped in a contest, since it is somewhat obvious.

Comment: @DS The reasoning is easy but I am not sure if we can say directly "(U,V,W) majorizes (X,Y,Z)".

Comment: Ok thanks. And I know this isn't the right place as it is not much related, but I wanted to ask how you approach inequalities where we can't directly apply well-known theorems; and any other manipulations reverse the inequality? Contests nowadays usually ask such questions (like APMO 2024, none of my friends got the inequality)

Comment: @DS I know little about that. Usually I motivate my solution by computer, although often it is verifiable by hand.